# Why does compiler complain that superclass has no constructor, when the default constructor is 'automatically' given to a class with no constructor?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, constructor, default-constructor

> All classes have at least one constructor. If a class does not
>   explicitly declare any, the Java compiler automatically provides a
>   no-argument constructor, called the default constructor. This default
>   constructor calls the class parent's no-argument constructor, or the
>   Object constructor if the class has no other parent. **If the parent has
>   no constructor (Object does have one), the compiler will reject the
>   program.**

([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html))

But then, `Object` is a (direct or indirect) superclass of every class in Java.

Suppose, we have a class `A`, which does not extend any class explicitly, so it implicitly extends `Object`. Also suppose, `A` does not explicitly provide a constructor, so the compiler adds to it a default constructor automatically, which will call the construtor of its superclass, `Object` (and `Object` does have a constructor).

Now suppose we have a class `B` which extends class `A`, and it does not provide an explicit constructor, so the compiler automatically supplies it with a default constructor; this default constructor tries to call a constructor from `A`.

**Now why a Compiler Error in `B`, when the compiler *has* provided a (default) constructor to `A` (which is calling `Object`'s constructor, and `Object` has one)?**

---

**EDIT:**

*Test: Compiles Successfully! **Does that mean the last sentence in the tutorial is incorrect?***

```
class A extends B {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        //A a = new A();
        System.out.println("Yayyy");
    }
}

class B {
}
```

Comment: Did you test this out?  I would absolutely expect that to work.

Comment: @LouisWasserman No, trusted it because it is in *official* Java tutorial.

Comment: Just because it's official doesn't mean it makes sense. It _just said_ that all classes have at least one constructor at the beginning of the paragraph!  So there's no such thing as having no constructor.

Comment: @Downvoter Do you mind sharing the reason for the downvote?

Comment: @azurefrog Please see the quote from the official tutorial, the last sentence of which is in the bold face. My question is based on that. I didn't know exactly what words would the compiler choose to describe the error; but the statement in the quote does tell what the problem is - the statement says the compiler complains, and the question is *why* does the compiler compain.  Is that the reason of the downvote?

Comment: @Solace Re: downvote: I haven't the foggiest, I wasn't the downvoter.  I'm just confused as to what you're asking, since your question implied to me that you had gotten an error that I'm unable to reproduce.

Comment: @azurefrog Please gimme a min, Testing it, will update the exact words of the error.

Comment: @azurefrog Updated the question. The test compiles successfully. Does that mean the statement in the tutorial is wrong?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Updated the question. The test compiles successfully. Does that mean the statement in the tutorial is wrong?

Comment: Not so much wrong as meaningless, IMHO.  Since Object has a constructor and is a superclass of every other class, the implication is that while it is technically true that classes whose parent have no constructor will be rejected, there are no cases where this can occur.  Maybe there are edge cases allowed by the JLS?

Comment: @azurefrog I don't yet know what JLS is, and I am pretty certain that this tutorial is for beginners. They wouldn't (shouldn't) expect *that* level of sharp analysis  from a beginner. =s but whatever is the case, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Solace JLS stands for [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/).  It's the document that literally defines the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly some terminology:

- **No-args constructor:** a constructor with no parameters;
- **Accessible no-args constructor:** a no-args constructor in the superclass visible to the subclass. That means it is either public or protected or, if both classes are in the same package, package access; and
- **Default constructor:** the public no-args constructor added by the compiler when there is no explicit constructor in the class.

So all classes have at least one constructor.

Subclasses constructors *may* specify as the first thing they do which constructor in the superclass to invoke before executing the code in the subclass's constructor.

If the subclass constructor does not specify which superclass constructor to invoke then the compiler will automatically call the accessible no-args constructor in the superclass.

If the superclass has no no-arg constructor or it isn't accessible then not specifying the superclass constructor to be called (in the subclass constructor) is a compiler error so it *must* be specified.

For example:

```
public class Base { }
public class Derived extends Base { }
```

This is fine because if you add no constructor explicitly Java puts in a public default constructor for you.

```
public class Base { }
public class Derived extends Base { public Derived(int i) { } }
```

Also fine.

```
public class Base { public Base(String s) { } }
public class Derived extends Base { }
```

The above is a compilation error as Base has no default constructor.

```
public class Base { private Base() { } }
public class Derived extends Base { }
```

This is also an error because Base's no-args constructor is private.